# Swift: syntax explanation - round brackets then "in"

Tags: ios, swift

I following tutorial and confused with following code:

```
 let rectToDisplay  = self.treasures.reduce(MKMapRectNull){

            (mapRect: MKMapRect, treasure: Treasure) -> MKMapRect in

            let treasurePointRect =
                MKMapRect (origin: treasure.location.mapPoint, size: MKMapSize (width: 0, height: 0))

            return MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, treasurePointRect)
        }
```

In fact, I'm not understand only that line:

```
    (mapRect: MKMapRect, treasure: Treasure) -> MKMapRect in
```

Is that some kind of function or something? What is the output? Im not quite understand meaning of that construction `(struct: struct, someClass: someClass) -> Struct in`

What is that logic? What is the meaning of "in"?

If you wondering, `treasure` is custom class that contain coordinate properties - latitude, longitude, etc.

I understand the "whole" meaning of that code snippet, but syntax of that line confuse me a bit..

Could you provide an explanation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_151

Comment: Link is not an explanation.

Comment: Requesting someone to copy and paste the documentation is not a question ...

Comment: Exactly! I didn't request to copy and paste, but to provide an explanation (look at my last sentence). At least you could say that it is Closure Expression Syntax, instead of link to developer.apple.forum.. Still thank you, link was helpful.

Comment: It's not a link to a forum, it's a link to the documentation.  The documentation for Swift is extremely good and very clearly answers your last couple questions.  You should review it.

Comment: I didn't mean link to "forum" i just copy part of your link, and of course, everyone is familiar to that book provided by Apple. As for me, that book is large and i doubt everyone learning Swift and asking question read it from begin to an end. In fact, there is a lot of questions that may be answered with link - "go here to developer.apple.com and don't waste our time". Sometimes you want more "friendly" and readable explanation, that why i came here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for documentation copy-paste.

Comment: @gnasher729 so please, don't do that and close thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift there are two ways to declare a function: with `func`, and with a closure expression:

```
// this is a function that takes an Int and returns a String
func f(i: Int) -> String { return i.description }
f(1) // returns "1"

// this is also a function that takes an Int and returns a String
let g = { (i: Int) -> String in return i.description }
g(1) // returns "1"
```

The latter is a closure expression – a quick way of defining a new function inline.  They are most commonly used with functions that take functions (for example `map`, which takes an array and a function that transforms an element of that array, and runs the function on each element creating another array).

The syntax for closure expressions is they start, within braces, with arguments and return type, and then an `in`, and then the function body.  Unlike with `func`, which starts with the `func` keyword, then the arguments and return type, followed by the function body within braces.

You don't always see the `in` because it can be left off.  There are lots of shorthands that allow you to skip the arguments and return type (and the `return` keyword) altogether.  But sometimes you need to give them, and then you need the `in` keyword.

You can read more about closure expressions in the [Apple Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_151).  You can read more about functions and closure basics [here](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/11/a-basic-tutorial-on-functions-and-closures-in-swift/).